# Why is GCC warning me about a useless cast when using an inherited constructor?

Tags: c++, gcc

Consider the following C++ code:

```
#include <string>

struct A {
    A(const std::string& s): s(s) {}
    std::string s;
};

struct B: A {
    using A::A;
};

int main() {
    B b("test");
}
```

When I compile it via GCC 6.2.1 with the `-Wuseless-cast` parameter

```
g++ -std=c++14 -Wuseless-cast test.cpp -o test
```

it emits the following warning:

```
test.cpp: In constructor ‘B::B(const string&)’:
test.cpp:9:14: warning: useless cast to type ‘const string& {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&}’ [-Wuseless-cast]
    using A::A;
             ^
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:13:15: note: synthesized method ‘B::B(const string&)’ first required here
    B b("test");
              ^
```

However, when I change the definition of `B` to

```
struct B: A {
    B(const std::string& s): A(s) {}
};
```

the warning goes away.

Questions:

- Why is the warning emitted?
- Why does specifying a constructor for `B` instead of inheriting it from `A` fixes the warning?

Comment: Looks like a gcc bug to me.

Comment: I think what's going on is that the standard says that [the inherited constructor forwards the arguments along with `static_cast<T&&>(p)`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.inhctor#8), and GCC [dutifully emits those casts literally](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/0e9ab2f06d6470b72268aecc944e6c626fadad36/gcc/cp/method.c#L489) - and then they got caught by `-Wuseless-cast`.

Comment: @T.C. May make sense to post this to BZ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example can be further reduced to:

```
struct A {
    A(const int& i): i(i) {}
    int i;
};

struct B: A {
    using A::A;
};

int main() {
    B b(0);
}
```

That is an [open issue](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70844) on GCC.
Including `<string>` isn't apparently required to reproduce it.
Note that the issue is still unconfirmed and it is known to affect at least GCC 6.1 - by looking at your question I would say that it affects also GCC 6.2.

Comment: Your example doesn't repro on Wandbox's 6.2.0, unlike OP's. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Ei522Nd72lVNwS4z

Comment: Repro in GCC Bugzilla is the shortest anyway.

Comment: @T.C. [Fixed](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1YXOCyImAPAqMhXo). I'm updating the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably facing a known GCC bug ([PR 70844](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70844)).

Comment: The example from the linked bug report does not reproduce on GCC 6.2, unlike mine: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/CyuDhv6RJ6PL0qxq

Comment: @skypjack Yes, the updated one you gave in your answer is reproducible, thank you.